# ruby RSS parser not returning correct information

Tags: ruby, xml, rss

I need some help understanding how the Ruby [rss](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html) parser works. I'm trying to access to the content of the first 10 entries from this [feed](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/feed/atom.xml) with this code:

```
URL = 'http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/feed/atom.xml'
...

def initialize(versionName)
  open(URL) do |rss|
    feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)

    feed.entry(1..10).each do |entry|
      @attributes[:descriptions][:"#{versionName}"] = entry.content
    end

  end
end
```

While debugging, I realized `entry.content` doesn't give me the correct data. Instead, it gives me [this endless data](http://pastebin.com/axTV6F5Z) which even causes my console to get stuck. Anyone could tell what would be the correct way to parse my feed in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry.content` is an instance of `RSS::Atom::Feed::Entry::Content`:

```
feed.entry(1..10).first.content.class
# => RSS::Atom::Feed::Entry::Content < RSS::Element
```

It has a bunch of public methods that could allow you to inspect the tag's content, including `content` and `to_s`. You can inspect it's public methods by looking up the documentation or by doing: `entry.content.public_methods`.